# How to delete Voice Memos on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program, mojave

I've been trying Mojave for a while, and I've been using Voice Memos, but I can't find a way to delete recordings.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slide the recording to the left to access the Delete button, or continue sliding to delete instantly.

[image]

Alternatively, choose Edit, select the recording to delete, then choose Delete.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, mobile touch gestures on macOS. :/

Answer (score 2):

Just press Backspace button to delete it.